# Why encode url parameter if contains # symbol

Tags: forms, spring, google-app-engine, get

I'm passing a URL parameter to a form via a get request. I need to URL encode the parameter when the parameter contains a '#' . Otherwise the request fails. Why is this required ? Why do I need to URL encode the '#' parameter but not other text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> '#' is used in URLs to indicate where a fragment identifier 
> (bookmarks/anchors in HTML) begins.
> ```

The part following the `#` is never seen by the server. It is generally used for navigation at the client-end.
The **[following characters](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#whatwhy)** need to be encoded in order to be used literally.

Answer (score 0):

When using GET,  anything after `#` (and the # itself) will not be seen by the server.